# spring boot slow jsp loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I just began learning spring boot and I can make common mistakes

when i used my application from eclipse on localhost it load jsp pages very fast, but when i do it from host i wait about few second on each page

database is always remote

i tried launch it on several servers, from small vps to hetzner's dedicated server with i9900k

it isn't database problem, i have already tested this, it takes in about 30ms

on host i launch it by "mvn spring-boot:run", because it easy to deploy with git

```
@Controller
public class CourseSelectorController extends DataController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index", "/courses"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(Model model)
    {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.addAttribute("nonParsedJSONCourses", new FrontCourseSelector(courseService.getCoursesWithStatus(CourseStatusEnum.STARTED)));
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

        return "course/CourseSelector";
    }
}
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.pa4ok</groupId>
    <artifactId>csplatform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>csplatform</name>
    <description>Remote studing web service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- utils -->

        <!-- docker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.docker-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- docker -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://123.123.123.123/name?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.maxLifetime=180000000

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

my webconfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer 
{    
    @Bean
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor() 
    {
        return new BeanFactoryPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException 
            {
                BeanDefinition bean = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
                bean.getPropertyValues().add("loadOnStartup", 1);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) 
    {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Give it more memory

Comment: i tried use "export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx4096m", but nothing changed

Comment: Give the host where your code runs more memory.

Comment: i9900k, 64gb ddr4 and ssd on hetzner dedicated server is not enough?

Comment: Yes, If the JVM gets enough of it. Can you attach a profiler to see where the time is spent?

Comment: can you recommend a suitable tool for this or throw off the link to the article?

Comment: visualvm is the place to start for Java, unless you use netbeans.    https://visualvm.github.io/